# NextJS with Serverless Mysql Error - Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, connection

**Many People are facing this issue with no answers on StackOverFlow. Someone please provide an answer**

I started building an app in NextJS, followed few tutorials to connect the app to mySql but no matter what i do i am always presented by an error saying in the console. This error occurs the moment i import the **serverless-mysql** package.
**Module not found: Can't resolve 'net' , 'tls' & 'fs'**

Here is the code in index.js file which is located in /pages/ folder.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql'



export default function Home() {
  return (
    "The Default Boilerplate HTML Code goes here, it was too long hence not posting it
```

Here is the code in data.js file which is located in /pages/ folder

```
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql';
const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD
  }
});
export default async function excuteQuery({ query, values }) {
  try {
    const results = await db.query(query, values);
    await db.end();
    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

my nextjs.config file code

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    'MYSQL_HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'MYSQL_PORT': '3306',
    'MYSQL_DATABASE': 'nearcal',
    'MYSQL_USER': 'root',
    'MYSQL_PASSWORD': '',
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I dont know why React is so overhyped where doing a simple thing is so complicated. The LAMP stack provides a full packed solution. MERN is really messy

Comment: You're getting the error because you're importing a Node.js library in client-side code. You should only use `serverless-mysql` in server-side code, like inside [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) or [`getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview).